# ¿Cómo ordenar los nombres de las columnas de un reporte de Excel hecho en Python?

Tags: python, excel, ordenar, reporte

Tengo los datos en una hoja de Excel que leo con Python para luego generar un reporte pero las columnas que tienen los meses las muestra en orden alfabético, ¿cómo puedo ordenarlos de enero a diciembre?

```py
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
    
archivo_excel = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
    
tabla_pivote = archivo_excel.pivot_table(index=('PROVINCIA','DISTRITO', 'TIPO JUZGADO','DEPENDENCIA','AÑO'), columns='MES', values='-PROCESOS PRINCIPALES RESUELTOS',aggfunc='sum')#.round(0)
    
df = tabla_pivote.query("AÑO == 2021")
    
df.to_excel('Rpt_Prod.xlsx', startrow=5, sheet_name='Produccion')
```

Así es como genera el reporte, pero con los meses ordenados alfabéticamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi es el archivo de excel donde se encuentran los datos iniciales
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin ver como están estructurados los datos de origen es dificil dar una respuesta concreta, pero usar la opción [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) de pandas podría ser la más eficiente.

Simplemente tienes que indicar en qué orden quieres que aparezcan las columnas de tu dataframe, de este modo:

```
df = df.reindex(columns = ['PROVINCIA','DISTRITO', 'TIPO JUZGADO','DEPENDENCIA','AÑO','ENE','FEB','MAR', 'ABR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AGO', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DIC'])
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, pero me muestra un error:" TypeError: Expected tuple, got str" y respecto a  la hoja de excel de donde se extrae los datos la columna mes tiene estos datos en forma vertical: ENE, FEB ,MAR, ABR, ..., DIC

Comment: Si colocas el código justo después de la línea 'df = tabla_pivote.query("AÑO == 2021")', y antes de enviarlo de vuelta al excel, debería funcionar. De todos modos, necesito datos para poder reproducir el error. Ni tengo tu código, ni los datos de origen que muestras en la foto me sirven para reproducirlo. ¿Puedes pasar el df que resulta después de la línea de código que te he indicado? Con eso creo que ayudaría mucho.

Comment: Muchas gracias Jose Luis, estas en lo correcto colocando el codigo en el lugar que indicas ordena las columnas solo deje los meses como columnas. df = df.reindex(columns = ['ENE','FEB','MAR', 'ABR', 'MAY', 'JUN', 'JUL', 'AGO', 'SEP', 'OCT', 'NOV', 'DIC'])